# Is there a formula to convert minutes to hours? (not division by 60)

Tags: sql, sql-server, math

Is there a way to convert minutes to hours?

Like I have a 405 minutes, how can I get 6H45 or 6,45 hours out of it?

If I do 405/60 it gives me 6,75.

But I want 6,45.

I need it in my SQL query. Thank you in anvace.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.) Column data type?

Comment: SQL Server. Column as INT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate Hours and minutes separately and concatenate the valueS like below

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ROUND(405/60,0)) + 'Hrs ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CEILING(405%60)) + 'mins'`

This will give you `6Hrs 45mins`

Comment: Awesome! It works. Do you now how to perform it mathematically (out of SQL)? Like I have 20,75 I wont to turn it to 21,15. Like if tenth value gets to 60, we do plus 1 to whole.

Comment: @AlexMcManns This is so needlessly complicated... Why not keep this within a proper type like [TIMESPAN](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/working-with-time-spans-and-durations-in-sql-server). You could do all the *maths* with appropriate functions and choose a final output format when you need it...

Answer (score 3):

From your comment I get, that the column with Minutes is of type `INT`. This should not result in `6.75`, when divided by 60...

Use integer divsion and modulo:

```
DECLARE @minutes INT=405;
SELECT CAST(@minutes/60 AS VARCHAR(10))+'H' + CAST(@minutes % 60 AS VARCHAR(2))
```

The integer division will calculate `405/60` to a plain `6` and `405 mod 60` will result in `45`. Both parts can be casted to string and concatenated.